# Python - Can't concatenate more than 1 non-ascii string

Tags: python, string

I'm trying to create a new string containing more than 1 string with special characters in it. This doesn't work:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
str1 = "I am"
str2 = "español"
str3 = "%s %s %s" % (str1, u'–', str2)
print str3
>> Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "myscript.py", line 5, in <module>
    str3 = "%s %s %s" % (str1, u'–', str2)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 4: ordinal not in range(128)
```

The strange thing is that if I delete the `ñ` or the `–` character, it creates the string correctly:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
str1 = "I am"
str2 = "espaol"
str3 = "%s %s %s" % (str1, u'–', str2)
print str3
>> I am – espaol
```

or:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
str1 = "I am"
str2 = "español"
str3 = "%s %s" % (str1, str2)
print str3
>> I am español
```

What is wrong about it?

Comment: `"español"` → `u"español"`

Comment: the string with "español" is took from a database so it's in a variable, i've tried with unicode(str2) but still doesn't work

Comment: works fine on Python 3.5.2

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I doubt that, since it includes a Python 2 `print` statement.

Comment: @Hyperion Then the database code or the data in the database is the cause of the problem.

Comment: @KlausD., I said that it works on Python 3.5.2, no doubts

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest: sure, but *this is not Python 3*. The Python 3 equivalent is using `bytes` objects with `str` objects. The errors will be immediate and no implicit decoding takes place, so it won't work for `ASCII`-only strings either.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, I see that. And it's good time to think about upgrade

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing Unicode strings and byte strings. *Don't do that*. Make sure all your strings are of the same type. Preferably, that's `unicode`.

When mixing `str` and `unicode`, Python *implicitly* will decode or encode one or the other type using the ASCII codec. Avoid implicit operations by **explicitly** encoding or decoding to make everything one type.

This is what is causing your `UnicodeDecodeError` exception; you are mixing two `str` objects (byte strings, `str1` and `str3`), but only `str1` can be decoded as ASCII. `str3` contains UTF-8 data and thus decoding fails. Explicitly creating `unicode` strings or decoding your data makes things work:

```
str1 = u"I am"     # Unicode strings
str2 = u"español"  # Unicode strings
str3 = u"%s %s %s" % (str1, u'–', str2)
print str3
```

or

```
str1 = "I am"
str2 = "español"
str3 = u"%s %s %s" % (str1.decode('utf-8'), u'–', str2.decode('utf-8'))
print str3
```

Note that I used a Unicode string literal for the formatting string too!

You really should read up on Unicode and codecs and Python. I strongly recommend the following articles:

- Ned Batchelder's [*Pragmatic Unicode*](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html)
- Joel Spolsky's [*The Absolute Minimum Every Programmer Must Know About Unicode*](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/)
- The [Python Unicode HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html)